# How to increase cursor size programmatically?

Tags: terminal, applescript, script, cursor

How do I increase the cursor size programmatically? I know [how to do it manually](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18427?locale=en_US). Is there a script that can do it from the command line rather than an AppleScript that does it from the GUI.

### Why?

I do a lot of customizations to my Mac, but I also create new users all the time. To save time, I would like to programmatically achieve certain customizations.

Comment: Another good reason to do this programmatically is to be able to turn back on a cursor that has disappeared with a click from the Dock.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the *command line command* `defaults`, which can `read` and or `write` the *value* of the `mouseDriverCursorSize`*key* in the`com.apple.universalaccess` *.plist* file, the `write` *command*, e.g. `defaults write com.apple.universalaccess mouseDriverCursorSize 2.5` doesn't take immediate affect and may actually get overwritten before the change can take effect. Note: The `mouseDriverCursorSize` *key* in `com.apple.universalaccess` *.plist* file does not exist unless the *default value* has previously been changed.

While you said you didn't want to go the **GUI** route with e.g. **AppleScript**, how about you split the difference and do it from the *command line* using `osascript` to process the **AppleScript** *code*, which does make the change from **System Preferences**, but **without being interrupted** by the **System Preferences UI**. As a matter of fact, assuming the **System Preferences Dock Tile** is still present, as is its default, all you'll see is the **System Preferences Dock Tile** bounce once, and no **System Preferences UI**. (This assumes it wasn't open to begin with.)

**If that's acceptable**, then the following **AppleScript** *code* saved as a *command line executable* will do the job:

- **Note:** The *value* shown for `theCursorSize`  is what my system is presently set to.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

    -- # set theCursorSize between 1.0 and 4 (Valid intermediate values may run out 12 decimal places.)

set theCursorSize to 1.388884782791

    -- # Get the system minor version number, as an integer.

set theSystemVersion to system version of (system info)
set TID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"."}
set theMinorSystemVersion to text item 2 of theSystemVersion as integer
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

    -- # Change the size of the mouse cursor.

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Display" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    delay 0.5   -- # Modify as/if necessary. Value is in seconds as a decimal number.
    tell application "System Events"
        if theMinorSystemVersion is equal to 8 then
            set value of value indicator 1 of slider 2 of group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences" to theCursorSize
        else if theMinorSystemVersion is equal to 9 then
            set value of value indicator 1 of slider 2 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences" to theCursorSize
        else if theMinorSystemVersion is greater than 9 and theMinorSystemVersion is less than 13 then
            set value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences" to theCursorSize
        end if
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

**Note:** As coded, this *script* works with **OS X 10.8** through **macOS 10.12**. I have not tested this under **macOS High Sierra**, however if nothing has changed between **macOS 10.12** and **macOS 10.13** with this particular *object*, then the `less than 13 then` *code segment* can be changed to `less than 14 then`, or if you prefer, shorten the line of *code* to just:

```
else if theMinorSystemVersion is greater than 9 then
```

To create a *command line executable*, containing the above **AppleScript** *code*, do the following in **Terminal**:

```
touch cmcs
open cmcs
```

- Copy and paste the above **AppleScript** *code* into the opened `cmcs` document.
- Set the *value* of `theCursorSize` to your preferred cursor size.
- Save the document, pressing: **⌘S**

Back in **Terminal**, make `cmcs` *executable*:

```
chmod u+x cmcs
```

Now the `cmcs` *command line executable* can be executed by typing: `./cmcs`

- **Note:** If you place the `cmcs` *command line executable* in a location defined within the `PATH` *environment variable*, you can omit the leading `./`, and or having to type `/path/to/cmcs`. Also note that the naming of, `cmcs` is for *change mouse cursor size*, and can be whatever you want it to be otherwise.

**Additional Notes:**

The *value* of `mouseDriverCursorSize` *key* in the `com.apple.universalaccess` *.plist* file is stored rounded to the 6th decimal place, e.g, `1.388884782791` is saved as `1.388885`

To get the full *value*, in **Script Editor**, run the following *script*:

```
set theSystemVersion to system version of (system info)
set TID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"."}
set theMinorSystemVersion to text item 2 of theSystemVersion as integer
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Display" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    delay 0.5 -- # Modify as/if necessary. Value is in seconds as a decimal number.
    tell application "System Events"
        if theMinorSystemVersion is equal to 8 then
            get value of value indicator 1 of slider 2 of group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
        else if theMinorSystemVersion is equal to 9 then
            get value of value indicator 1 of slider 2 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
        else if theMinorSystemVersion is greater than 9 and theMinorSystemVersion is less than 13 then
            get value of value indicator 1 of slider 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
        end if
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

---

**Update to address comment:**

If you're wanting to run this each time a **User** *logs in*, the I'd do the following:

In **Automator** create a new *Application workflow* and add a **Run AppleScript** *action* to it.

In the **Run AppleScript** *action*, replace `(* Your script goes here *)` and `return input` with all but the *shebang* (`#!/usr/bin/osascript`) of the first **AppleScript** *code*. The *shebang* isn't necessary since this is being run in an **Run AppleScript** *action* vs. a **Run Shell Script** *action*.

Save the **Automator** *Application workflow* as e.g. **Set Mouse Cursor Size** in the **/Applications** folder.

In **System Preferences**, do two things...

- In **Users & Groups** > *select* target **User** > **Login Items** and add **Set Mouse Cursor Size** to the list of **Login Items**.
- In **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**, add **Set Mouse Cursor Size** to the **Allow the apps below to control your computer** list.

  - Note: the above is for OS X 10.9 and later. For OS X 10.8, **Accessibility** and *check* the **Enable access for assistive devices** *check box*.

Then each time the **User** *logs in*, the **Set Mouse Cursor Size** will run and do as programmed.

Comment: one comment: you're giving me an executable script.. but is there a way to make this script execute by default everytime a user is logged in or something? ie the same way my ~/.bash_profile executes and makes my terminal colorful etc.. is there a way to make this script execute automatically as well?

Comment: @abbood, Please see the **Update to address comment:** section. added to the bottom of the original answer. to address your comment.

Comment: here is a follow up quesiton: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299118/where-is-the-reference-to-find-out-how-to-customize-mac-behaviour

Comment: after running this command i saw the icon in the dock bounce just like you mentioned, but the cursor remained the same size

Comment: How did you figure out some details of programmatic names and handles like `Seeing_Display` that correspond to the GUI ? This no longer works since macOS Ventura where "System Settings" is totally changed, but I'm having hard time modifying it to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Javascript code for macOS Monterey:

```
function fn() {
    const cursorSizeSmall = 1 
    const cursorSizeLarge = 4
    
    const isRunningSystemPreferences = Application('System Preferences').running()
    Application('System Preferences').panes.byId('com.apple.preference.universalaccess').anchors.byName('Seeing_Cursor').reveal()
    const process = Application('System Events').processes.byName('System Preferences')
    while (process.windows.length == 0) {}
    const window = process.windows[0]
    while (window.groups.length == 0) {}
    const group = window.groups[0]
    while (group.tabGroups.length == 0) {}
    const tabGroup = group.tabGroups[0]
    while (tabGroup.sliders.length == 0) {}
    const slider = tabGroup.sliders[0]
    if (slider.value() == cursorSizeSmall) {
        slider.value = cursorSizeLarge
    } else {
        slider.value = cursorSizeSmall
    }
    if (!isRunningSystemPreferences) {
        Application('System Preferences').quit()
    }
}

fn()
```

You can use this snippet in the "Script Editor" app to create a new JXA script (make sure to set the language to JavaScript):

[image]

or use the Shortcuts app introduced in Monterey ([link](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/67a9336ca88d4e04a994bf9caca0428c)).

Comment: How can this be used/called?

Comment: @nohillside check my updates

Comment: Great. So `osascript -l JavaScript FILE.js` would also work I assume.