# Different cursor sizes for each monitor (Full HD, 4K)

Tags: display, mouse, dock

Edited: Maybe to rephrase my question, is there a way to have different cursor sizes for each screen when a MacBook has external monitors connected? The built-in MacBook Pro screen is a retina display scaled at 1792 x 1120. I also have a 4K monitor connected. On the 4K monitor the mouse cursor is incredibly small and hard to find.

I can make the cursor size bigger in System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display -> Cursor, but then the cursor is too big for the smaller resolution.

Is there any option or app that automatically adjusts the cursor for each monitor?

---

Original question: Is there a way to make the mouse pointer bigger but only when the MacBook is docked (lid closed, clamshell mode) and using an external display?

The problem is that when I dock my laptop and use my 4K display, the mouse pointer is so small I can hardly see it. I can then make the pointer bigger by going to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display -> Cursor. That works fine. However once I undock the MacBook and start using the regular screen again, I need to go into the cursor settings again to revert the changes.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say docked do you mean closed clamshell mode?

Comment: Yes, by docked I mean lid closed and external monitor connected.

Comment: I’m assuming you’ve already rejected the display settings to increase menu bar size and pointer size for retina type displays? A picture of your display settings would make this very clear how you’ve set things up.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what display settings you are referring to. I have a Macbook Pro 16 2019 model. It's a retina display for the built in screen. Inside of System Preferences -> Displays, the resolution is set to default for all screens. Inside of Accessibility -> Display -> Cursor, when I change the cursor size its not screen specific and the same cursor size is used across all screens.

Comment: Maybe to rephrase my question, is there a way to have different cursor sizes for each screen when a MacBook has external monitors connected?

Comment: Interesting question! To clarify, do you ever use the MacBook’s internal display *and* an external display at the same time (as extended desktop, not mirroring)? Relatedly, do you ever use the MacBook in mirroring mode with an external display, such as when giving a presentation? I would want to account for those possibilities in approaching an answer to your question.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the 4K display in a Retina scaling? That would solve the problem immediately.

Comment: @benwiggy: I’ll bet #Aedan is trying to squeeze more usable desktop area from the 4K display. (I can relate: I have multiple *24"* 4K displays that I run at native [non-Retinized] resolution. )

Comment: There's potentially the beginnings of an Applescript method on SO - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521682/how-to-adjust-the-cursor-size-using-applescript There's also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298550/how-to-increase-cursor-size-programmatically Neither of which I am competent to comment on, much less adapt to this particular usage ;))

Comment: @ jdmc I never use the internal screen and the external screen together because I have a docking station for the MacBook which requires the lid to be closed for the external monitors to get connected. The annoying thing is that once I undock the laptop and continue work using the internal screen, the cursor is huge and I need to manually change it in the settings.

Comment: @benwiggy It's exactly like jdmc said. I require the full 4k resolution area available (web developer) so I can split the available space into 4 sections, each the resolution of a 1080p screen. This allows me to have Chrome, Safari and Firefox open at the same time, plus developer tools in the remaining space. This setup is a massive time saver to see all browsers live at the same time while developing.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you. I came across that thread as well. I guess if there is no automated solution, some command line script or AppleScript that gets triggered via keyboard shortcut will have to do.